# Act on event of change of iframe url

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, cross-domain

Okay, so I read and I read, but I couldn't figure out what to do with it. 
My situation is this : 
A blog is hosted inside my university and is accessible just inside the university.
That bums me out because I want to check it when I am at home. Trust me, if this goes through I will report it to the proper authorities in the university. 
So what I did was this: I uploaded a PHP script in my webspace in the university which used the webspace offering server(inside the univ domain) to grab the HTML in the blog, and output it to my homepage inside an iframe.

The problem :
Whenever I click on any of the links inside the iframe, it redirects to the original page in the blog and so I am not able to read it.

I started by reading up on addEventListener. Then I thought about outputting the output of the PHP file directly into this page using document.write(). (But that would cause my original js to disappear, and I don't want that). I saw the multitude of posts announcing the forbidden nature of cross-domain JS access. So the idea of fetching the URL after I click on the link on the blog inside the ifram and get the 403 forbidden, and then loading the iframe again is gone too.

Any suggestion are welcome.

Cheers,
AJRocker

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of that kind of redirecting is that every link has the target attribute with "_top" value to prevent this kind of injection into iframes.